# My mixin class is causing my classes to become static - PHP

Tags: php, object, this, mixins, self

So this is my mixin class:

```
class AisisCore_Loader_Mixins {

    private $_classes;

    private $_class_objects = array();

    private $_methods = array();

    public function __construct(){
        $this->init();
    }

    public function init(){}

    public function setup($class){
        if(!is_array($class)){
            throw new AisisCore_Loader_LoaderException('Object passed in must be of type $class_name=>$params.');
        }

        $this->_classes = $class;
        $this->get_class_objects();
        $this->get_methods();    
    }

    public function get_class_objects(){
        foreach($this->_classes as $class_name=>$params){
            $object = new ReflectionClass($class_name);
            $object_name = get_class($object);
            $this->_class_objects[$object->name] = $object->newInstanceArgs($params);
        }
    }

    public function get_methods(){ 
        foreach($this->_class_objects as $class_object_name => $class_object){
            $this->_methods[$class_object_name] = get_class_methods($class_object);
        }

        return $this->_methods;
    }

    public function __call($name, $param = null){
        foreach($this->_methods as $class_name=>$methods){
            foreach($methods as $method){
                if($name === $method){
                    return $this->isParam($class_name, $method, $param);
                }
            }
        }

        throw new AisisCore_Loader_LoaderException("Method: " .$name. 
                            " does not exist or it's access is not public");
    }

    private function isParam($class_name, $method, $param){
        if($param != null){
            call_user_func(array($class_name, $method), $param);
        }else{
            call_user_func(array($class_name, $method));
        }        
    }
}
```

Pretty simple stuff, load a set of classes, allow you to call their functions and so on, but we have a new issue. It seems that classes passed into this are instantiated as static, thus their methods cannot use `$this->` they are resorted to using `self::` which is wrong.

Lets see an example of how this all works:

```
class BaseBridge extends AisisCore_Loader_Mixins{

    public function __construct(){ 
        parent::construct();

        $this->setup(array('ClassB' => array()));
    }
}
```

Lets Define `ClassB`

```
class ClassB{

    public function __construct(){}

    public function some_method(){
        $this->_some_private_method();
    }

    private function _some_private_method(){}
}
```

Pretty basic stuff, so lets hook it all up in `ClassA`

```
class ClassA extends BaseBridge{

    public function __construct(){ 
        parent::__construct(); 
        $this->some_method();
    }
}
```

**Quick Review:** We have a core class, `ClassA` which extends `BaseBridge` which is our bridge class between one or more (meant to be used with more) classes that `ClassA` extends from. In this case were only extending from `ClassB` for simplicity.

**Whats the issue?** See, how in `ClassB`, were doing: `$this->_some_private_method();` ya that's going to epically and catastrophically fail. *Why?* because I get the error: `Using $this when not in object context` which makes me so confused, so I change it to: `self::$_some_private_method();` and it works like a charm.

Why? and what do I have to change or fix to make it so that `$this` can be used in a class being instantiated through the mixin class?

Comment: There's a reason multiple inheritance isn't supported in many languages, and you should really stop trying to force PHP to do something it wasn't meant to do...

Comment: Flagged for not being constructive. @MarcB Things might not be easy But I managed to get this far.

Comment: My first suggestion is to avoid mixins/traits entirely. *Usually* if the answer is multiple inheritance or horizontal code reuse you're asking the wrong question. My second suggestion is that if you absolutely must do this ... stop trying to implement mixins yourself. Just upgrade to PHP5.4 and use [traits](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php) as part of the language.

Comment: One: WordPress users use 5.2.x, no can do. Two: Implementing mixins isn't that hard, im just having a small issue. and Three I would love to go to 5.5.x but again WordPress. @rdlowrey

Comment: This question highlights one of the core issues with Wordpress and it's plugin ecosystem: compatibility mayhem. Most (*any I've dealt with*) hosting providers support 5.4; it's nearing the end of 2013 and so should you. Don't shoehorn a language feature that has existed for 19 months. Upgrade.

Comment: @DanLugg http://t.co/9bV7XxwLsQ explains why I cant upgrade to 5.4

Comment: @LogicLooking No, it doesn't; it explains why you've chosen to continue the trend of supporting outdated versions of PHP in the Wordpress plugin development community. That aside, 5.4 supports traits in a predictable way, and it would be pragmatic of you to leverage them.

Comment: @DanLugg If I do that I might as well go to 5.5 and support less then 5% of the community. I need to support as many people as possible for the Framework. That's like you building something in PHP 6 and every ones on php 5.4 and maybe 2% are on 6.

Answer (score 0):

So with some slight modifications, I have managed to make this work. How ever I do not believe that a function with multiple arguments will work - Feed back appreciated.

```
class AisisCore_Loader_Mixins {

    private $_classes;

    private $_class_objects = array();

    private $_methods = array();

    public function __construct(){
        $this->init();
    }

    public function init(){}

    public function setup($class){
        if(!is_array($class)){
            throw new AisisCore_Loader_LoaderException('Object passed in must be of type $class_name=>$params.');
        }

        $this->_classes = $class;
        $this->get_class_objects();
        $this->get_methods();    
    }

    public function get_class_objects(){
        foreach($this->_classes as $class_name=>$params){
            $object = new ReflectionClass($class_name);
            $this->_class_objects[$object->name] = $object->newInstanceArgs($params);
        }
    }

    public function get_methods(){ 
        foreach($this->_class_objects as $class_object_name => $class_object){
            $this->_methods[$class_object_name] = get_class_methods($class_object);
        }

        return $this->_methods;
    }

    public function __call($name, $param = null){
        foreach($this->_methods as $class_name=>$methods){
            foreach($methods as $method){
                if($name === $method){
                    return $this->_is_param($class_name, $method, $param);
                }
            }
        }

        throw new AisisCore_Loader_LoaderException("Method: " .$name. 
                            " does not exist or it's access is not public");
    }

    private function _is_param($class_name, $method, $param){
        if($param != null){
            $this->_param_is_array($class_name, $method, $param);
        }else{
            call_user_func(array($this->_class_objects[$class_name], $method));
        }        
    }

    private function _param_is_array($class_name, $method, $param){
        if(is_array($param)){
            call_user_func_array(array($this->_class_objects[$class_name], $method), $param);
        }else{
          call_user_func(array($this->_class_objects[$class_name], $method, $param));  
        }        
    }
}
```

Now functions inside of classes that are registered by this class can use `$this->`.

The issue is that I am not sure if multiple param based functions will actually work.